# How to use AREL eq() method in a where with joined data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I currently have this scope:

```
class User

  has_many :inbox_messages, :through => :message_users do
    def unread
      published.where(:message_users => { :sender => false, :trash => false , :deleted => false}).where(MessageUser.arel_table[:read_at].not_eq(nil))
    end

  end
end
```

And it's working. But I was wondering if there is way to merge the second `where` into the first one.

Comment: are both `where` clauses for the same table (i.e., the table that MessageUser uses)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you should be able to do that with

```
published.where(:message_users => { :sender => false, :trash => false , :deleted => false, :read_at => nil })
```

Comment: Then you DO need it as a separate `where` statement that uses something like `.arel_table[:read_at].not_eq(nil)`, since you can't mix that into the existing Hash you have passed in the `:message_users` option.

Comment: There is also the open source [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) library which makes these kinds of expressions more natural with a custom DSL (e.g., you could use `!= nil`). See its docs for details.